# How to execute js/jquery code after the ajax callback function is called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a simple warehouse information system as a web app using js and php. The system basically separates the warehouse storage into blocks that contains several levels. Let's say the warehouse contains 9 rows and 9 columns (like a 9x9 matrix). So the warehouse has 81 blocks. Each block has 5 levels.

In my frontend I have an empty 5-row table for displaying the levels of a block. I wrote a js/jquery function 'blockRender(currentBlock)' to render the levels of the block. The function uses ajax call to extract data about the status of the block from php backend. The success callback of the ajax will render the occupied level's background into grey(Empty levels have no background).

Now I want to write normal js code to check if a level is occupied. What I did is firstly calling blockRender(currentBlock), then I check whether this level(table row) is rendered into grey so that I will know if it is occupied.

Something like this:

html:

```
    <table>
       <tr id="lv_1"/>
       <tr id="lv_2"/>
       ...
       <tr id="lv_5"/>
    </table>

//js
function blockRender(currentBlock){
   $.ajax({
     success: function(){
       //render the table
     }
   });//
};

blockRneder(currentBlock);

if(document.getElementById("lv_1").style.background == "grey"){
  alert("occupied");
}else{
  alert("empty");
}
```

But the problem is: the normal js code is always executed before the ajax callback even if I call the render function first. So I always get a completely empty table (all the rows have no background color) because it always check the status before the table is rendered.

How could I let the 'blockRender(currentBlock)' render the table first, and then execute my js code for checking block status?

PS: 'blockRender(currentBlock)' itself works fine. It can always extract data and render the block successfully.

Comment: you don't show any code, therefore you probably won't get any help. Lets start with this AJAX call shall we?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of js.
You need to determine in which order things are executed programmatically.

Either:

```
function doThisFirst(x){
  $.ajax({
      url: 'someurl', 
      success: function(result){
        thenDoThis(result)
    }
  });
};

doThisFirst(x);

function thenDoThis(result) {
  if(document.getElementById("lv_1").style.background == "grey"){
    alert("occupied");
  }
  else{
    alert("empty");
  }
}
```

or

```
function doThisFirst(x){
  $.ajax({
      url: 'someurl', 
      success: function(result){
  if(document.getElementById("lv_1").style.background == "grey"){
    alert("occupied");
  }
  else{
    alert("empty");
  }
    }
  });
};

doThisFirst(x);
```